# Can't get nested_form to show validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, nested-forms

I haven't had a problem with validations before but this time I am having issues with nested_form validations. I am using Twitter Bootstrap and can get flash errors to show with, say, this:

```
 def create
 @recipe = current_user.recipes.new(params[:recipe])
 if @recipe.save
  redirect_to my_recipes_path, :notice => "Thanks #{current_user.name} Recipe sucessfully created."
  else
  render :action => 'new'
 end
end
```

For my flash messages I use this in my app/layouts

```
 <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
 <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
 </div>
 <% end %>
```

So I thought I would try and just get one of the validators working, so my model

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
delegate :name, :to => :user, :prefix => :user, :allow_nil => true
belongs_to :country
has_many :ingredients 
has_many :preperations
has_many :favourites
```

validates_presence_of :dish_name

and my form

```
    <%= nested_form_for @recipe  do |f| %>

    <div class="field_with_errors"> 
    <%= f.label :dish_name, "Dish Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :dish_name, :placeholder => "Enter Dish Name" %>
    </div>


    <%= f.label :country_id, "Country Of Origin" %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:country_id, Country.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Please select country') %>

    <%= f.label :category, "Category" %>
    <%= f.select :category, [['Starter'], ['Main Course'], ['Desserts'],  ['Vegeterian']], {:include_blank => 'Please Select'} %>


   <%= f.label :difficulty, "Difficulty Level" %>
   <%= f.select :difficulty, [['Beginner'],['Intermediate'],['Expert']], {:include_blank => 'Please Select'} %>

   <%= f.label :preperation_time, "Preperation Time (Mins)" %>
   <%= f.select :preperation_time, [['15-30 Mins'],['30-60 Mins'],['60-120 Mins']], {:include_blank => 'Please Select'} %>

   <%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |ing| %>
   Ingredient<br>
   <%= ing.text_field :ingredient_name , :placeholder => "Enter Ingredient Here" %><br>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.link_to_add "Add an Ingredient", :ingredients %><br>

   <%= f.fields_for :preperations do |prep| %>
   Preperation Step<br>
   <%= prep.text_field :prep_steps , :placeholder => "Enter step Here" %><br>
   <% end %>

   <%= f.link_to_add "Add a step", :preperations %><br>

   <%= f.label :description, "Description of Recipe" %>
   <%= f.text_area :description, :size=> "60x10" %></br>

   <%= f.file_field :avatar %><br>

   <%= f.submit "Submit Recipe" %>
   <% end %>
```

I am fairly new to Rails so I may have missed something fundamental, or is it because it is a nested form and it behaves differently?

### Edit

Output of `<%= flash debug %>`:

```
  --- !ruby/object:ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash
 used: !ruby/object:Set
 hash: {}
 closed: false
 flashes: {}
 now:
```

Comment: Hmm.. can you add the line `= debug flash` to your view code and attach the output(after you fail to submit a form) to your answer? Also while not immediately relevant to the question at hand you might find more success with changing the line `<div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">` to `<div class="alert alert-<%=(name == :notice && 'success' or name == :warning && 'warning' or name == :info && 'info' or 'error')%>">` if you want to make use of the additional alert messages that Twitter Bootstrap supports. Otherwise you will only get success or error.

Comment: apologies but never used this before, how would it look in the view?

Comment: thanks for the bootstrap tip :)

Comment: Oh Sorry, that was haml code. Right ontop of `<%= nested_form_for @recipe  do |f| %>` add the line `<%= debug flash %>`

Comment: updated with output of <%= flash debug %> added to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're not actually providing your flash hash with any messages to work with. A quick solution might be something like:

```
def create
 @recipe = current_user.recipes.new(params[:recipe])
 if @recipe.save
   redirect_to my_recipes_path, :notice => "Thanks #{current_user.name} Recipe sucessfully created."
 else
   flash[:error] =  @recipe.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
   render :action => 'new'
 end
end
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, though nothing has changes, still get returned to the new action (form) with no error messages shown

Comment: brilliant, now shows as a bootstrap error :), why does this now work, is it because it s reindering the view first and treating it as a brand new form?

Comment: That's actually a good question, the initial syntax I provided `render :action => 'new', :flash => {..}` is actually old rails 2.3 style syntax. From my understanding it was taken it and just recently put back in. My best guess is it's because we're both using different versions of Rails, it works for me on 3.2.8 however.